# Pandas: Set first 2 hours of every group to NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I am trying to clean my data by setting 'value' to NaN for the first 2 hours of every 'state' group.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=6, freq='H')
>>> 
>>> data = {'value': np.random.rand(len(rng)), 
...         'state': ['State 1']*3 + ['State 2']*3}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=rng)
>>> 
>>> df
                       state     value
2016-01-01 00:00:00  State 1  0.800798
2016-01-01 01:00:00  State 1  0.130290
2016-01-01 02:00:00  State 1  0.464372
2016-01-01 03:00:00  State 2  0.925445
2016-01-01 04:00:00  State 2  0.732331
2016-01-01 05:00:00  State 2  0.811541
```

I've come up with three ways of doing this, and both don't work:

1) First attempt using .loc and/or .ix result in no change:

```
>>> df.loc[df.state=='State 2'].first('2H').value = np.nan
>>> df.ix[df.state=='State 2'].first('2H').value = np.nan
>>> df
                       state     value
2016-01-01 00:00:00  State 1  0.800798
2016-01-01 01:00:00  State 1  0.130290
2016-01-01 02:00:00  State 1  0.464372
2016-01-01 03:00:00  State 2  0.925445
2016-01-01 04:00:00  State 2  0.732331
2016-01-01 05:00:00  State 2  0.811541
```

2) Second attempt results in an error:

```
>>> df.loc[df.state=='State 2', 'value'].first('2H') = np.nan
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

3) This is a hackish attempt that worked, but is apparently discouraged:

```
>>> temp = df.loc[df.state=='State 2']
>>> temp.first('2H').value = np.nan
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2698: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[name] = value
>>> df.loc[df.state=='State 2'] = temp
>>> df
                       state     value
2016-01-01 00:00:00  State 1  0.800798
2016-01-01 01:00:00  State 1  0.130290
2016-01-01 02:00:00  State 1  0.464372
2016-01-01 03:00:00  State 2       NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00  State 2       NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00  State 2  0.811541
```

Ideally, I want to determine an easy way to loop over each group and clean the beginning and end of their respective data groups. I was under the impression that .first and .last would be great due to their simple time string formats.

Using .loc doesn't take into account these time string formats, but I'm probably missing something.

What's the true way of doing this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all `indexes` by first `2H`, then change `index` to `Multiindex`, [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for matching [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
idx = df.groupby('state')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.first('2H')).index

df.set_index('state', append=True, inplace=True)
df = df.swaplevel(0,1)

df.ix[idx,'value'] = np.nan

print (df.reset_index(level=0))
                       state     value
2016-01-01 00:00:00  State 1       NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00  State 1       NaN
2016-01-01 02:00:00  State 1  0.406512
2016-01-01 03:00:00  State 2       NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00  State 2       NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00  State 2  0.226350
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the data is evenly spaced and indexed by hours. I want to take advantage of the df.first('2H') functionality to take care of unique but inconsistently spaced data

Comment: Incredible - this is exactly what I was looking for.